# Deduplication: how to implement content-defined chunking?

Tags: algorithms, optimization

I'm writing deduplication program that implements content-defined chunking. Just now i know 3 algorithms to do it ([hashing a fixed-size window and selecting hashes < maxuint/N](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/dce.html#Section_527), [hashing an order-1 bounded window](http://encode.ru/threads/456-zpaq-updates?p=29800&viewfull=1#post29800), and [local maxima chunking](http://research.microsoft.com/~gurevich/Opera/183.pdf)). Are you know other algorithms or ideas to improve these ones? My goal is to get best compression for a given average chunk size.

A few deduplication-related links:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_deduplication
http://encode.ru/threads/1726-Deduplication-X-Files

Comment: Can you provide more background? I can't understand the question.

Comment: i think it's just because it's rather narrow area. the most famous software employing deduplication is probably rsync. nowadays much faster algorithms with content-defined chunking (CDC) are used. ideally, i want to understand how to construct better CDC algorithms in order to improve compression ratio. but this probably needs either specialist in these algos or scientist who are interested to learn these area

Comment: I think the entire term should be deprecated, if not banished as a dysphemism pushed by marketing of a company that shall go unmentioned for this very reason. `rsync` is _not_ about detecting circumstantial multiplication and attempting to reduce the ensuing increase in cost: it is about keeping in check the cost of keeping _intentional_ copies synchronised.